# What is every possible way a PC can breathe underwater?

Tags: dnd-5e, underwater, breathing

Currently my group is planning an underwater strike on an underwater city. We are wondering what are all the possible ways we could get to breathe underwater.

So far we have found:

- Cap of Waterbreathing
- Potions
- Be a Triton
- Be a druid and use Wild Shape
- *water breathing* (spell)
- Apparatus of Kwalish

Comment: Are you the DM or a player? I ask because the subset of what is actually available in your world matters more than what the total set of options are.

Comment: This question is well in-scope -from review.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a list.

#### Magic Items

- Black/Green Dragon Mask
- Breathing Bubble (*Explorers Guide to Wildemount*)
- Cap of Water Beathing
- Cloak of the Manta Ray
- Dekella, Bident of Thassa (*Mythic Odyssey of Theros*)
- Helm of Underwater Action
- Necklace of Adaptation
- Potion of Water Breathing
- Powered Armor
- Ring of Water Elemental Command
- Ventilating lungs
- Wand of Polymorph
- Wave

#### Spells

- *Alter Self*
- *(True-) Polymorph*
- *Shapechange*
- *Water Breathing*

#### Racial Traits

- Amphibious (Triton, Water Genasi)
- Child of the Sea (Sea Elf)
- Constructed Resilience (Warforged)
- Underwater Adaptation (Simic Hybrid)
- Unending Breath (Air Genasi)

#### Class Features

- Bestial Soul (Path of the Beast, Barbarian)
- Experimental Elixer (Alchemist, Artificer)
- Gift of the Depths (Eldritch Invocation, Warlock)
- Gift of the Sea (The Fathomless, Warlock)
- Replicate Magic Item (Artificer)
- Revelation in Flesh (Aberrant Mind, Sorcerer)
- Storm Soul (Path of the Storm Herald, Barbarian)
- Wild Shape (Druid)

Comment: Couldn't a non-magical technological item, depending on the setting, also enable water breathing?

Comment: @DLynch Sure, but homebrew items are outside the scope of what belongs in this answer.

Comment: I agree, I just wasn't sure if there were any published settings or resources that included a sufficiently technological solution. Closest I can think of would be the magi-tech of Eberron.

Comment: You forgot gillyweed... Oh wait, wrong universe.

Comment: In an emergency, you can use shape water on a 5 foot cube of water to create a 'bubble' of water with no water in the center, allowing a creature to breathe for up to an hour as long as they don't exit their 5 foot cube, or as long as they recast the spell on their next destination space. Don't get grappled while using this trick, though.